# Applinig restrictions to the shopping cart

Tags: javascript

When I receive input by -prompt- (for example banana) it should receive the next value from me and finally show my cart but I do not see any result. Why?

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>basket</h2>

<p id="myBasket"></p>

<script>
const Basket=[];
let sum=0;
const i=0;
while(sum<=10){
  Basket[i]=prompt("Enter a fruit name");
switch(Basket[i])
{
  case "banana":
    sum+=5;
    break;
  case "grape":
    sum+=3;
    break;
  case "apple":
    sum+=2;
    break;

}
  i++;
}
for(item in Basket){
document.getElementById("myBasket").innerHTML = Basket[item];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look in your JS console.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change `const` variable.

Here an example how to fix it:

```js
let Basket=[]; // here don't set const
let sum=0;
let i=0; // same, don't use const
while(sum < 10){
  Basket[i] = prompt("Enter a fruit name");
  switch(Basket[i]) {
    case "banana":
      sum+=5;
      break;
    case "grape":
      sum+=3;
      break;
    case "apple":
      sum+=2;
      break;

  }
  i++;
}
for(item in Basket){
  document.getElementById("myBasket").innerHTML += Basket[item] + "<br>"; // warn: here all next item was overwritting old item
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

  <h2>basket</h2>

  <p id="myBasket"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

To debug your javascript, you can use F12, and see in "Console" tab all error that are produced.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to write code that exits the loop as soon as it exceeds 10?
Apparently the loop is repeated once more

Comment: it's because you wrote `<=`. If you write "banana" you will have 10, and so you will already be lower or equals to 10. To fix it, you just have to set `<`

Comment: I just edit the answer. If it well reply to your question, you can accept it :)

Comment: thanks, But The problem still persists, try a banana and three apples:?

Comment: No: if you wirte 2 times banana it's fine (5+5 so 10, and so it's finished)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your for loop you should affect `item` and not `Basket[item]`. And use a foreach loop instead

```
Basket.foreach ( item => {
    document.getElementById("myBasket").innerHTML = item;
})
```

Here is the doc for the foreach just in case
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach